# tooltip hover just works sometimes

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip, delay

I am trying to implement a `Tooltip` in a loop, for displaying some words after hovering over a rectangle. The problem is that, the words just show up once in a while (sometimes even without a delay, sometimes not even after waiting for a minute). When I put the tooltip statement outside of the loop the words always show up (with a short delay), but I need the statement inside. Any idea what causes the problem?

```
for (int i = 0; i < finalList.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < names.getName().size(); j++) {
        Label number = new Label(" " + finalList.get(i).get(j).getNamesFrequencySection());
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle();
        rec.setY(j * 20 + 20);
        rec.setX(i * 80 + 100);
        rec.setWidth(80);
        rec.setHeight(20);
        if (finalList.get(i).get(j).getNamesFrequencySection() == 0) {
            rec.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        } 
        else {
            rec.setFill(Color.rgb(250 - (3 * finalList.get(i).get(j).getNamesFrequencySection()), 0, 0));
        }
        number.setLayoutY(j * 20 + 20);
        number.setLayoutX(i * 80 + 130);
        root.getChildren().add(rec);
        root.getChildren().add(number);
        Tooltip.install(rec, new Tooltip(finalList.get(i).get(j).getMostCommon().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]","")));

    }
}
```

`NamesFrequency` is an Integer and `getMostCommon()` is the String of the words.

Comment: can you provide a bit more context? what's around that for-loop? where is it executed?

Comment: Yup, you need to tell us more. How do you do it outside the loop? What is `finalList`? Is it `List<List<Something>>` where `Something` is the class with method `getMostCommon()`? If so, how is `Something` class defined? How is `finalList` populated and how does it interact with other things?

Comment: Finallist ist a List<List<Name>> and Name is an object with a String and an Integer value. The idea is, that I have a text sperated (outer List) into sections and each section contains names (inner List), each name has a string with some words (getMostCommon) and an Integer (getNamesFrequency) with the frequency (in the section). The output is a tabular with sections (columns), names (rows) and in each cell is the frequency and after hovering over it should display the getMostCommon() words. Everything works quit well,  except the hovering with tooltipp.

Comment: Is `finalList` populated asynchronously? Or populated after you do the looping?

Comment: befor the loop I have initialized finalList with:     `ArrayList<ArrayList<Name>> finalList = wBA.fourWordsBeforAfter(names.getName(),
     wordList, stopWords);` The finaList is return value of a funtction (wBA).

Comment: Yes, you need to give a [mcve]. Your codes are too complex and we are lacking too many pieces of information to figure out what is going on. You are likely to find out the reason while trying to create such an example. Alternatively, step into your codes, find out what is going on.

Comment: Did you test it with something simple as  `Tooltip.install(rec, new Tooltip(i +" "+j));` ?